# Remove .php from URL and create unfriendly url

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I want http://www.example.com/youtube/youtube/details/abvcde instead of http://www.example.com/youtube/youtube/details.php?id=abvcde   i want to unfriendly URL, remove .php and ?id

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^youtube/youtube/details/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /youtube/youtube/details.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```